# How to create separate list for every incoming message using socket?

Tags: socket.io

i have a list of contacts using socket i am sending one to one messages but on receiving message how to attach new incoming message to desirable messages list  . by doing this message is attached with opened list .

```js
   var messagelist = document.getElementById("messagess");
   io.on("new_message",function(data){
    let messagebox = document.createElement("div");
    let message = document.createElement("p");
    let id = document.createElement("p");
    id.innerText=sender;
    message.innerText=data.msg;
    messagebox.appendChild(id);
    messagebox.appendChild(message);
    messagelist.appendChild(messagebox);
   
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
var messagelist = document.getElementById("messagess");

// Create an unordered list element
let list = document.createElement("ul");

io.on("new_message", function(data) {
    let messagebox = document.createElement("div");
    let message = document.createElement("p");
    let id = document.createElement("p");
    id.innerText = sender;
    message.innerText = data.msg;
    messagebox.appendChild(id);
    messagebox.appendChild(message);

    // Create a separate list element
    list.appendChild(messagebox);
})

// Append the list element to the messagelist container
messagelist.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: what about previous messages ?  need to attach new message with old messages list .

Comment: Sorry, that's the best I could come up with.